# Differentiability of a particular function at the Origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to check the differentiability at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ of the function:$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy^{2}}{y^{2}+|x|}\,\,(x,y)\ne (0,0)\\0 \,\,(x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$.
Now, setting up the usual differentiability limit in two-variables and noticing that: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$; $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$, and that $f(0,0)=0$, I arrive to the limit: $lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy^{2}}{(y^{2}+|x|)\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$. I started with checking the restriction to lines of the form $y=mx$ and the limit is independent from $m$ and equals $0$. From now on I don't know how to treat this, as I suppose the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ so I have to do some inequality to show that the limit is indeed $0$.

Comment: Squeeze theorem is your best friend.

Comment: I'm re-doing the exercise; how should I squeeze the function $\frac{xy^{2}}{(y^{2}+|x|)\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$ ? @NinadMunshi